# Is the following mapping a function or not

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A := B := \{x \in \mathbb R :  -1 \leq x \leq 1\}$ and $C$ is a subset of $ A \times B $ defined as $C := \{ (x,y) : x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\}$. Is this mapping a function? (I know that this is the equation of a circle so it must be a function, right?)I'm unable to figure out why this is not a function whereas $ f(x) = x^{2} $ is a function.

Comment: Try to answer the question; why could it _not_ be a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function you cannot, per definition, map an element in the domain ($A$, in your example) to more than one element in the codomain ($B$). More precisely in this case, you can only have one tuple $(x,y)$ in $C$ for each $x$. Here you have both $(0,1)\in C$ and $(0,-1)\in C$ right? You of course have more duplicates. As a matter of fact, you have duplicates for all $x$-values except for $x=-1$ and $x=1$, right?

Geometrically: If the graph is a circle, it is not a function since you would map one element in the domain to two different elements in the co-domain. Say you plot the circle in the xy-plane, then for one x-value, you would have two y-values. Per definition of a function, this is not allowed. With $f(x)=x^2$ on the other hand, you still only have one value for $f(x)$ for each value of x, so that is a function.

You might want to recap the definition of a function, and also of injective function, as I think you might be mixing the definitions up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that explained a lot. The function here is defined as $f: A \times B \to C$, right?

Comment: @Chaitanya No: it is a function $C:A\to B$. This is the ordered-pair description of a function.

Comment: First of all, there is no function but I get what you mean. It would otherwise have been $f:A\to B$. The function, if it was one, would have been the subset of $A\times B$, i.e $C$ would have been your function. A function can simply be seen as the subset (C in your case) of $A\times B$. Then you can call it $f$ if you want, and say $f:A \to  B$ since each tuple $(x,y)\in C$ represents an allocation of $y$ to $x$.

Comment: @Christopher.L I didn't think of it that way. Read it somewhere but now I get what are sets $A, B$ and $C$. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $A \times B$ represents a function if and only if for each $a \in A$ there is one and only one ordered pair $(x,y) \in A \times B$ such that $x=a$.

This is not the case for $C$ as both $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ belong to $C$.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the subset $C$ as an implicit function. In this case given by
$f(x,y)= x^2+y^2-1= 0$.

Anyway, there is a theorem (the implicit function theorem : [ref. thm. wiki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)) which say you that any implicit function can be represented locally by a function.

For example, in your case you can only represent the upper part of the circle as a function but not the whole circle.

I hope is enough for you. Let me know if you want more details.

Sorry for my english :-)